# How to Create a non-empty File inside a Folder from the Menu

Tags: lubuntu, navigation

The OS that I'm using is Lubuntu, so my navigation menu is "File Manager PCMan FM", but I can install any file manager if this works and solves my problem.

I am a python developer and what I want to do is create some folders everyday and put inside them a python script, which is a text file ending in .py, in order to work inside the folders. That python script enables me to work in my projects in the folder and I can easily run it via the terminal.

Instead of copy-pasting it into every folder, is there a way to paste it from the menu, like FIle -> Create New -> a.py

Comment: What do you mean with "non-empty"?

Comment: A file that I have wrote and saved somewhere containing content, script lines, and ending in .py. I just want to be able to paste it from the menu, not going to where I saved it, copy it, and then come back to the new folder to paste it...

Comment: Have you looked into a clipboard manager such as clipit but this does not solve the question you are asking to create a non empty file from pcmanfm.